not able detect deeplink from push notification notification when using fcm api in react native
I am using firebase to send push notification to my react native app.
I am able to send notification to both android and iOS.
I am using https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send to send notification. Below is the body which I am sending to the api.
{
    "to": "token",
    "notification": {
        "body": "body",
        "title": "title",
        "subtitle": "subtitle"
 
    },
    "data": {
        "gcm.n.link": "myApp://?screenName=TradeDetail"
    }
}

Then I am using Linking to get the url:
Linking.getInitialURL()
  .then((initialUrl) => {
    console.log("initialUrl: ", initialUrl);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error getting initial URL:", err);
  });

In android I am able to get url:
initialUrl:  myApp://?screenName=TradeDetail
But in iOS I am getting null
Is there something else which I should be sending in body of my api. Or is there something which I need to get url detected in iOS
